# Batch cut / explode

Tags: batch-file

I have text like

```
AU,Australia,0,null,54,21
CZ,Czech Republic,5,50,45,80
....
```

And i want output like this:

```
"Australia",
"Czech Republic"
```

and other script for output:

```
{ "54", "21" }
{ "45", "80" }
```

Is it somehow possible using .bat file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First script :

```
@echo off&cls
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%1 in (input.txt) do echo %%1
```

Second script :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=5,6 delims=," %%1 in (input.txt) do echo {"%%1","%%2"}
```

**EDIT :**

Third Script :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%1 in (input.txt) do (
set $var=%%1
if /i "!$Var:~0,1!"=="A" echo %%1
)
```

The input file is `input.txt`

Comment: Thanks, that works :) Is it possible to print it only if it starts with letter "A" ?

Comment: Check Third Script in the new EDIT

Comment: I strongly encourage you to NOT use `%%1` as FOR replaceable parameter; there is not one advantage to use digits instead of letters and you will be confused with `%1` Batch file parameter sooner or later...

Comment: Thanks @Aacini you're right. I just did it in this case to make @Michal Heneš anderstand how the `TOKENS` works. And is also good to know that you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not (for now) interested in Batch programming, I just needed to ekvivalent for cut -d "," f [NUMs]... One more question, can i make such a thing ? :
if /i "!$Var:~0,2!"=="Aa" echo %%1

Comment: Yes you can but, in this case you do not have to use the `/i` "case insensitive" switch.